# Why there is $address->hasCouponCode() in qoute's _validateCouponCode() function?

Tags: magento-enterprise, quote, address, coupon, coupon-codes

I'm just courius why there is check for `$address->hasCouponCode()`
in `_validateCouponCode` (`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`).

I think that there is no such data in model nor in database like coupon code for address.

I'm asking because our developers are overriding this method, and they are checking this condition but always `$address->hasCouponCode()` returns nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such method. It is called "magically" through the use of `__call`.
Calling `$address->hasCouponCode()` translates into calling:

```
isset($address->_data['coupon_code'])
```

of course you cannot use it directly like that because `$_data` is a protected member (I just wrote it here as a proof of concept).

The clean way to check is this:

```
$data = $address->getData();
$result = isset($data['coupon_code']);
```

The coupon_code can be set "on the fly" even if it's not saved in the database just by calling:

```
$address->setCouponCode(CODE HERE);
//or
$address->setData('coupon_code', CODE HERE);
```

Comment: in magento2 the `__call` method described above is a method of `\Magento\Framework\DataObject`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a coupon_code, it will be set in the Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\Discount::collect method.